# I want to use the normal for loop instead of the special one

Tags: java, class, object, arraylist, java-8

Contact is a public class with a parameterized constructor with `getPhoneNumber()` as one of the methods and the below code is  in a different class, where:

```
List<Contact> list=new ArrayList<Contact>();
```

This is the code I am using right now:

```
for(Contact contact:list)
{
  n=contact.getPhoneNumber();
  if(num==n)
    return contact
}
```

How to write this code in the below format:

```
for(i=0;i<list.size();i++)
{
...
...
...
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get-int-)?

Comment: *"This is the code I am using right now:"* What's wrong with it? Why switch away from it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please be advised, as [the help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) says, you’re supposed to search and research before considering asking a question here. I am writing this because I find that you question appears to be poorly researched.

Comment: "`if(num==n)`" this implies either that you are representing a phone number as a number (which is bad, e.g. because you can't represent a number starting with 0); or that you're comparing references by identity rather that equality (which is probably not what you really want).

Comment: Please notice that if at some point your list will be `LinkedList` then each get(index) will need to start from beginning, so to get N-th element it will need to iterate from 1,2,3,..N to get to your element making it very inefficient. Your current for-each loop solves this problem by internally using Iterator which remembers current element in list so it can simply jump to next one.

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing wrong with the enhanced `for` loop you're already using, and that's the way I'd write the code. But you've said you want to switch to the traditional `for` instead, so...

You do it basically the way you have, and use [`get`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#get(int)) within the loop body or (better in the general case) use a loop iterator (see [Andreas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59590410/157247) for more on using an iterator).

But:

1. You need to declare `i`.
2. I tend not to like to call `size` repeatedly, but instead to save it to a variable. That may be premature micro-optimization though.

So for instance:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    Contact contact = list.get(i);
    n = contact.getPhoneNumber(); // I assume `n` is already declared?
    if (num == n) {
        return contact;
    }
}
```

or

```
for (int i = 0, len = list.size(); i < len; i++) {
    Contact contact = list.get(i);
    n = contact.getPhoneNumber(); // I assume `n` is already declared?
    if (num == n) {
        return contact;
    }
}
```

But again, see [Andreas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59590410/157247) for an example using an iterator, which is the better choice in the general case.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to convert an *enhanced* `for` loop to a regular `for` loop, then you should look at the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2), which documents how the compiler does exactly that.

Your loop:

```
for (Contact contact : list) {
    n = contact.getPhoneNumber();
    if (num == n)
        return contact
}
```

gets converted to the following by the compiler *(since `list` is an `Iterable`, not an array)*:

```
for (Iterator<Contact> iter = list.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
    Contact contact = iter.next();
    n = contact.getPhoneNumber();
    if (num == n)
        return contact
}
```

The only difference between you doing it and the compiler doing it, is that you now have access to the `Iterator` variable, named `iter` in the code above.

---

***Warning:*** Do not use an index loop and `list.get(i)`, unless you're *absolute sure* the list is an `ArrayList` (or very small), and you know that the list will *never be changed* to something else in the future. Since such guarantees are very rare, just don't do it.

Lookup by index is very slow in lists such as `LinkedList`. Using an `Iterator` will perform good with all list types.

Comment: I don't know what I was thinking this morning. Of course use an iterator.

Comment: Using an iterator makes no difference, enhanced for-loop is just syntactic sugar for iterators, isn't it?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès As already mentioned in the answer, the compiler generates an iterator loop for the enhanced `for` loop, so you're correct.

Comment: @andreas My comment was more for T.J., using an iterator doesn't change anything...

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Then you should have used `@T.J.Crowder` to ensure TJ would be notified about your comment, and to clarify to others that you were talking to TJ, not commenting on the answer. Besides, TJ already acknowledged that he knows this, so your comment was really superfluous.

Answer (score 1):

In each iteration, you just need to get the contact using the `get(int)` method. From there on, the list's body should be the same:

```java
for (i=0; i < list.size(); i++) {
  Contact contact = list.get(i);
  n = contact.getPhoneNumber();
  if (num == n) {
    return contact;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer that you asked for. Whether it’s the answer that you should want, I am far from sure.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
    {
        Contact contact = list.get(i);
        String n = contact.getPhoneNumber();
        if (Objects.equals(n, num))
        {
            return contact;
        }
    }
```

I have assumed that `getPhoneNumber()` returns a `String` or `null`. It’s best to declare `n` inside the loop, but you must of course declare it the type that `getPhoneNumber()` returns. If it returns a primitive type (for example `int` or `long`, but not recommended), use `==` for comparison as in your question.

Both Andreas and Pshemo have warned against using `list.get(i)` as I do in this code in case the list gets replaced by a `LinkedList` or other list that hasn’t got constant time element lookup. First, no one should use `LinkedList` anyway. Second, if there are reasons to use `list.get(i)` (I don’t know what those reasons should be, though), guard against performance degradation by putting the following assert statement before the loop (and make sure you have assertions enabled on your development computer and in your test environment):

```
    assert list instanceof RandomAccess : "Check whether " + list.getClass() + " performs well enough";
```

**Or you may use a stream.** This certainly is not what you asked for, but if only for other readers I’d like to add that many programmers would prefer a stream operation:

```
    return list.stream()
            .filter(c -> Objects.equals(c.getPhoneNumber(), num))
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(null);
```